# How can I prevent Concrete5 from injecting <style> and <link> tags in the HTML body instead of head?

Tags: html, validation, content-management-system, concrete5

It causes my theme not to validate. And it's just plain wrong.

So why do they do it? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concrete5 doesn't generally do anything to your markup, instead it's most likely due to the markup from a block you've added to the page (of course some of the blocks could be the default ones that came pre-installed with the system, which is somewhat of an arbitrary distinction I suppose).

As frz mentions, if you can say which block(s) the offending markup is coming from then specific advice can be given about how to address it (and you will definitely get more responses over at the concrete5 forums about this than here on SO).

All that being said, one of the great features of Concrete5 is the ability to customize the templates of each individual block, so it's very likely these can be addressed without having to hack the core system or anything drastic like that. Also I know that they're working on cleaning up the markup for the pre-installed blocks for the next version to be released in a month or two.

EDIT: For future viewers of this question, the problem turned out to be that the <?php Loader::element('header_required'); ?> line was placed AFTER the closing </head> tag in the OP's theme template (that line of code is responsible for outputting all system css and js files, so it needs to be placed inside your theme's <head> section).

Comment: Actually it does. I built the theme from scratch. Even pages without any blocks whatsoever have the same problem. And it's because before when the page finally get's served there's <link> and <style> tags in the body, which are not in the original file.

Comment: Hmm... sounds strange -- there shouldn't be anything in the body except what you've specifically included in your theme templates. Do you have a link to this site I could look at by any chance? Also, it might be putting things like that in while you're in "edit mode", like for the controls that let you add and edit blocks -- but if you're just viewing the site as normal I've never seen it inject any of its own markup -- only the markup from the theme templates and whatever blocks you've added to the page.

Comment: Here ya go http://tacomamasla.nfshost.com/ . I'll probably post a link to a gist as well or something

Comment: I think your problem is that you've put the Loader::element('header_required') line outside of the <head> section in your templates -- move that line of code up so it's inside the <head> and all of the scripts and style references will be where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

generally we don't. It's possible that an add-on might, but there's ways for the add-ons to get their style sheets in the header like they should. This is probably an issue with a specific add-on, not a general concrete5 issue. You might have an easier time getting help on concrete5.org either as a support request for the add-on involved, or in the general building with concrete5 forum if you have some specific examples